# Reference react component at browser

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-dom

For simple testing purposes, I want to create an React app to render at browser via babel. So I do not use react starter kit.

So I have a very simple page like below;

```
 <script type="text/jsx" src="Link.react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">    
    ReactDOM.render(<Link page="https://www.facebook.com" />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Here `Link.react.js` has a react component like below;

```
export default class Link extends React.Component {
// basic implementation
}
```

But it does not render, and gives whole bunch of errors like

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
 React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Is there any way to achive this? Or I should use `react-scripts` utility to compile them first?

Comment: I don't know the right answer but you are getting **exports** is not defined in the error?

Comment: Right, and also some other errors. I updated my question.

Comment: Ok, I suspected that you did you write "exports" instead of "export" in your component but when I Google it I've seen that this is the regular error message. So, I think the problem is about exporting. Check your export part and even maybe just use old module.exports.

Comment: I tried, but did not worked :\